# SSL Certificate Chain error

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I am facing a weird issue .
Trying to get Web service call and certificate is configured to get the response.So,initially i imported the certificate from the browser and able to get the WS call successfully.

The issue is whenever i changed from one perspective to another like java to debug perspective i get certificate chain error.
the error is inconsistent.when i change the certificate in truststore (with all chained certificates) it is working, next day same will not work so again change to old certificate.
May be iam unable to put in right way but overall the issue seems inconsistent.Can anyone please tell me how this certificate chain works.

Really frustrated with certificate understanding.
BTW iam working with java 7

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue few time ago and i followed the following solution to get things start working.

**You will need to install your certificate under**

`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/`

just go to this directory and install your certificate.

**To install use the following command**

```
sudo keytool -import -file amirssw.cer -keystore cacerts
```

with this command you will able to install your certificate under keystore.

With this way you can get things under your control.

Please refer to the following links which may help you use the certificate properly.
http://blog.hexican.com/2010/12/sending-soap-messages-through-https-using-saaj/
https://ruelajingsantiago.wordpress.com/2013/08/16/saaj-web-service-client-over-ssl/

Cheers :)